# Angular: Sorting an array after an asynchronous call

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, service

I am using Angular in my project and I have a problem. In the controller I have two calls to the service which makes me fill in an array. After filling it out, I want to sort it out. The problem is that I don't know where in the code I have to do this. Does anyone know how to do it?

Next, I put the code:

This is the controller:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.loadOperations();
```

> **After this operation, I want sort the array "operationsListData" but it is empty**

```
  }

loadOperations() {
    this.operationsListData = [];
    this.operationsList = [];
    this.operationsService.getOperations(this.selectedVariable).subscribe(data => {
      this.operationsData = data;
      if (data.length != 0) {
        const variablesOperations = this.operationsData.map(p => p.variable_operations);
        var arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(variablesOperations[0]);
        arr.forEach(clave => {
          var name = variablesOperations[0][clave];
          this.operationsService.getOperationsByUuid(variablesOperations[0][clave], clave).subscribe(
            data => {
              data.name = variablesOperations[0][clave];
              this.operationsListData.push(data);
            },
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the service:

```
getOperationsByUuid(operation: string, uuid: string): Observable<OperationList> {
    return this.http.get<OperationList>(url, { params: new HttpParams().set('role', this.role) });
  }

getOperations(selectedVariables: any): Observable<Operations[]> {
    return this.http.get<Operations[]>(url, { params: new HttpParams().set('role', this.role) });
  }
```

Can someone help me?

- Angular version: 8.2.14

Comment: 1.Not sure, why you are pushing operationList to operationsListData. because nowhere you assigned operationList.

Comment: 2.If I understood correctly, you can sort it here ->  this.operationsListData.push(data);

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to sort them according to the name of the operation. I will modify the code to make it clearer

Comment: Your code is a hell of antipattern. Please get rid of the nested subscriptions with the help of rxjs operators. Currently you want to sort the array after all of the nested subscriptions have been called back, which you could only find out by comparing the resulting arrays length.

Comment: Oh!. Sorry. I am new in Angular. Thank you very much for the advice!! @MoxxiManagarm

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Can you help me? Can you write me what your idea would look like in code? Please, I've tried but I can't do it as you say

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put in specific indexes your `data` in `operationsListData` each time you enter in a subscribe fulfilled callback. For example, you can do something like :

```
loadOperations() {
    this.operationsListData = [];
    this.operationsList = [];
    this.operationsService.getOperations(this.selectedVariable).subscribe(data => {
      this.operationsData = data;
      if (data.length != 0) {
        const variablesOperations = this.operationsData.map(p => p.variable_operations);
        var arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(variablesOperations[0]);
        arr.forEach(clave => {
          var nombre = variablesOperations[0][clave];
          this.operationsService.getOperationsByUuid(variablesOperations[0][clave], clave).subscribe(
            data => {
              data.name = variablesOperations[0][clave];
              this.putDataInCorrectPlace(data); // <--
            },
            err => {
              var operationList: OperationList = {
                name: name
              }
              this.putDataInCorrectPlace(operationList); // <--
            }
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

And your function putDataInCorrectPlace:

```
private function putDataInCorrectPlace(data: YourType) {
    const index = this.operationsListData.length;
    this.operationsListData.map((operation, idx) => {
        if (operation.name < data.name) {
            index = idx // if data field is superior to operation field, we insert it
        }
    });
    this.operationsListData.splice(index, 0, data); // insert to determined index
}
```

This way, you are not forced to loop through your operationsListData array after completion to reorder, you do it at the same time you receive and put data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Use rxjs in the future as @MoxxiManagarm said.

```
 this.operationsService.getOperations(this.selectedVariable).subscribe(data => {
            this.operationsData = data;
            if (data.length != 0) {
              const variablesOperations = this.operationsData.map(p => p.variable_operations);
              var arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(variablesOperations[0]);
              let resultCount = 0;
              arr.forEach(clave => {
                  var name = variablesOperations[0][clave];
                  this.operationsService.getOperationsByUuid(variablesOperations[0][clave], clave).subscribe(
                    data => {
                      resultCount += 1;
                      data.name = variablesOperations[0][clave];
                      this.operationsListData.push(data);
                      if (resultCount == arr.length) {
                        //do your sort logic
                      }
                    },
                  );
                });
            }
          });
```